# ¿Cómo establecer ID en Table Blazor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, blazor

Tengo en un componente Blazor una   cuando intento establecer un id   me devuelve el error: ***El elemento Table No posee ningún atributo id***

¿Cuál es la forma de establecer este atributo este atributo en Blazor?

Necesitó ejecutar una función pasándole el respectivo id

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("initializeDataTable", "#miTabla");
```

HTML

```
           <Table>
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableHeadCell>Job</TableHeadCell>
                        <TableHeadCell>Date</TableHeadCell>
                        <TableHeadCell>Status</TableHeadCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    @foreach (var job in _jobs)
                    {
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>@job.JobTitle</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>@job.CreatedUtc.Substring(0, 10) </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>@job.Status </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    }
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
```

Comment: ¿Está usando su propio `Table` componente  o está usando un library / Nuget package?